# Existence of smooth hypersurfaces of given degree over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and a fixed integer $d \geq 1$, does there exist a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $d$? Does $d$ need to satisfy certain conditions for it to be true?

Over an algebraically closed field by the Bertini theorem it can be proven that their exist such a hypersurface. I don't whether the answer is true over finite fields. Is this is a hard question? Or is there a straightforward answer.

Comment: Yes: take the zero set of a polynomial of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables. (Depending on your defintions, you might want the polynomial to be irreducible.) Is the question why there is such a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbf F_q$?

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti I mean does there exist a homogeneous polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_q  [x_0, \dots, x_n]$ of degree $d$ such that the hypersurface defined by it is smooth.

Comment: This is a good question, and the answer is yes. See Section 3 of Poonen's paper: http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/projaut.pdf (see also Theorem 1.6 which says that there even exists a smooth hypersurface with no non-trivial automorphisms).

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar this looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

See Section 3 of Poonen's paper: www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/projaut.pdf

See also Theorem 1.6 which says that there even exists a smooth hypersurface with no non-trivial automorphisms.